# Is heart rate raw data available for developers via WatchKit?

Tags: apple-watch, watchkit

Is it possible to develop third party apps using Apple's WatchKit with an API for heart beat/rate data access/raw data access?

Is the WatchKit SDK publicly available for developers now?

Comment: WatchKit won't be out for some time yet. Wait until Apple sends you an email that it's out.

Comment: WatchKit will be released some time next month (November), at which point this information will become available.

Comment: WatchKit will be released in November of this year. Wait until then.

Comment: it is available now, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Heart Rate Raw Data information is **now available** in `Watchkit for watchOS 2.0`.

`WatchOS 2` includes many enhancements to other existing frameworks such as `HealthKit`, enabling access to the health sensors that access heart rate and health information in real-time.

You could check this information in the following session which is total 30 minutes presentation.If you do not want to watch entire session, then you directly jump to `Healthkit API` features which is in between 25-28 min:

[**WatchKit for watchOS 2.0 Session in WWDC 2015**](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=105)

Here is the source code implementation [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKWorkout_Class/)

Comment: What the maximum sampling frequency here. Can raw signal strength be output (i.e. faster than 1s sampling and showing signal attack and decay), or is it just the calculated heart rate?

Answer (score 4):

you can't access heart rate data in the raw - but watchkit is now at least available in limited form here - https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/

Comment: Is there any API that lets me access heart rate of users using watch?

Comment: @Smitha - Not yet. They will provide this most likely next year.

Comment: @Patrick Henshaw Can we get the heart rate using the Apple Watch using the HealthKit Framework and WatchKit Framework.

Comment: @annu unfortunately Apple hasn't released any sensor support (accelerometer, heart rate monitor, Taptic engine) :/ Hopefully this will be released in the near future but haven't heard much of when that would be - even though rumors are saying the WWDC

Comment: @PatrickHenshaw Thanks for your reply. You mean to say that in future version of iOS and Xcode it is possible that using iWatch we can get heart rate. Please go through this link http://techone3.in/ios-8-2-beta-released-with-watchkit-to-start-building-apple-watch-apps-2431/

Comment: it is available now, please see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has not provided any information about what APIs will actually be available in the WatchKit when it becomes available. As of today, Apple says they will release the first release of WatchKit in November 2014 (Next Month). As long as you are a registered developer, you will get an email when WatchKit is available.