# Is there a way to access the raw infrared data from the Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, watchkit

I would like to take the raw infrared data from the heart rate sensor on the apple watch to do calculations. Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758077/is-heart-rate-raw-data-available-for-developers-via-watchkit

Comment: check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858667/heart-rate-data-on-apple-watch/31165510#31165510

Answer (score 0):

Read the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/pre-release/)

You cannot access the heart rate sensor in the current SDK (watchOS1). Developers do have access to this sensor in watchOS2, currently in beta access for developers, which officially comes out to the public in November.